# export sqlite database data in to excel in android emulator

Tags: android, sqlite, export-to-excel

how can i export sqlite database data in to excel sheet by using CSV in android emulator?

this is possible or not?

please give some idea,I am new for android platform

Comment: Maybe this isn't a long term solution, but I have been able to make my app email my database, and then I use sqlite browser to export to csv.

Comment: Use an sd card image with the emulator. Use 'Pull' to copy the CSV file from your sd card image to the pc. When you are happy with the emulator test, install it on your test phone and use the USB connection to capture the CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

from [Sqlite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html)

Writing results to a file
By default, sqlite3 sends query results to standard output. You can change this using the ".output" command. Just put the name of an output file as an argument to the .output command and all subsequent query results will be written to that file. Use ".output stdout" to begin writing to standard output again. For example:

```
sqlite> .mode list
sqlite> .separator |
sqlite> .output test_file_1.txt
sqlite> select * from tbl1;
sqlite> .exit
$ cat test_file_1.txt
hello|10
goodbye|20
$
```

if you were to replace the separator character from '|' to ',' it might just work. of course you should learn how to use `sqlite3` from the shell to view table contents. it's much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently implemented the excel export function in my app. I have also included my full code on how to export filtered data to excel instead of the whole table.

You will need to create a second table for this. The second that will hold the data you require for this operation (In my second table I have removed my autoincrament ID column because I dont want it in my excel file).

You will need to clear the second table first and then add entries.

Then use the SqLiteToExcel object to export db to excel and save the file somewhere.

Then I have an email intent with the excel file attached for sharing (allows sharing with other apps other than email). here is my method:

```
    private void ExportData() {

     //CHECK IF YOU HAVE WRITE PERMISSIONS OR RETURN
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Storage permissions not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    //get database object
    myDbhelper = new MyDbHelper(getContext());
    SQLiteDatabase database = myDbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    //delete all entries in the second table
    database.delete("Table2",null,null);

    //Create a cursor of the main database with your filters and sort order applied
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            uri,
            projections,
            selection,
            args,
            sortOrder);

    //loop through cursor and add entries from first table to second table
    try {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            final String ColumnOneIndex = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("COLUMN_ONE"));
            final String ColumnTwoIndex = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("COLUMN_TWO"));
            final String ColumnThreeIndex = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("COLUMN_THREE"));

      //add entries from table one into the table two
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("TABLE2_COLUMN_1", ColumnOneIndex);
            values.put("TABLE2_COLUMN_2", ColumnTwoIndex );
            values.put("TABLE2_COLUMN_3", ColumnThreeIndex);

            database.insert("table2", null, values);
        }
    } finally {
        //close cursor after looping is complete
        cursor.close();
    }

     //create a string for where you want to save the excel file
    final String savePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/excelfileTemp";
    File file = new File(savePath);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
     //create the sqLiteToExcel object
    SQLiteToExcel sqLiteToExcel = new SQLiteToExcel(getContext(), "databasefile.db",savePath);

    //use sqLiteToExcel object to create the excel file 
    sqLiteToExcel.exportSingleTable("table2","excelfilename.xls", new SQLiteToExcel.ExportListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {

        }
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(String filePath) {
            //now attach the excel file created and be directed to email activity
            Uri newPath = Uri.parse("file://" + savePath + "/" +"excelfilename.xls");

            StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

            Intent emailintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            emailintent.setType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm email body.");
            emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,newPath);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailintent, "Send Email"));
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error msg: " + e);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed to Export data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I have this method implemented in my app and it works